# Chromium + Raw Html (directly from a C# string) + Angular => Problems when attempting to use routing

Tags: html, angularjs, routes, location, chromium

- CefSharp: 1.25.0 (based on Chromium 25.0.1364.152)
- Angular: 1.3.0-beta16
- UIRouter: 0.2.10

I'm developing a stand-alone C# application that uses CefSharp Chromium + Angular + UIRouter as the stack upon which the GUI will be relying on.

I hit it off by trying to make the above stack load the sample-code provided here:

http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angular-routing-using-ui-router

- For the sake of elegance the HTML + Javascript-libs of the GUI, get cobundled in a single resource file inside the .Net executable of the application.
- This resource is then passed programmatically during application-init to the Chromium control (by means of .LoadHtml) to be loaded *directly* into the browser, aka the HTML is *not* loaded from a separate .html file residing in the hard-drive or on a remote HTTP server. If the HTML gets loaded from the later ("standard") venues then everything works *flawlessly*.

I noticed that when loading the HTML directly as a string, as described above, the url of the resulting static web page (aka window.location) is set to 'about:blank'. It appears that angular has some sort of pet peeve with such a url, especially when it comes to using routing:

- First of all, the invocation of:

  ```
  history.pushState(null, "", url);
  ```

  inside

  ```
  self.url = function(url, replace) { ... }
  ```

  throws an exception ala

  ```
  Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18
  Error: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
      at Browser.self.url (about:blank:8004:21)
      at about:blank:10049:24
      at Scope.$eval (about:blank:11472:28)
      at Scope.$digest (about:blank:11381:31)
      at Scope.$apply (about:blank:11493:24)
      at about:blank:6818:15
      at Object.invoke (about:blank:7814:19)
      at doBootstrap (about:blank:6817:16)
      at bootstrap (about:blank:6827:14)
      at angularInit (about:blank:6796:7)
  ```

  the url that is passed to .pushState is:

  ```
  about:blank#/home
  ```

  which appears to be the result of concatenating 'about:blank' with the default state '/home'.
- Secondly, even if the above problem is solved there appears to be a major issue inside:

  ```
  $rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() { ... })
  ```

  which causes the following error:

  ```
  Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
  ```

  the reason is that when 'window.location' is set to 'about:blank' then

  ```
  $browser.url()
  ```

  always returns

  ```
  about:blank
  ```

  while

  ```
  $location.absUrl()
  ```

  returns

  ```
  about:blank#/home
  ```

  causing $watch to fire non-stop.

Is there any proper way to handle this shortcoming of angular when its dealing with web pages loaded directly into the browser in the manner described here?

If there is no workaround for this issue then I'm afraid that I will have to resort to loading the HTML directly from a file in the hard drive, which apart from being slower (can't cache the string to memory for subsequent usages), it's also a noticable deviation from the goal of developing a stand-alone-exe. :(

Thanks in advance and I apologize if this issue has been addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Firefox allows loading of external files within html file that loaded from "file:///...". but Chrome does not. in CefSharp(Chrome) you can do it in this way:

```
    // Allow angular routing and load external files
    BrowserSettings setting = new BrowserSettings();
    setting.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
    browser.BrowserSettings = setting;
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't allow to do AJAX on the file-system. But Chromium can be tweaked to do so:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(path);
browser.BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
browser.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrlsAllowed = true;
```